# Extjs app issue when not on localhost

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a simple application running on my localhost and in a UAT environment. There is a new component recently added and all is working well locally.

When I deploy the app to UAT i get the following 2 errors in the console.

```
/widget/label.js?_dc=1482256656320 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught TypeError: c is not a constructor(anonymous function) @ VM224:3Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.applyTabBar @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1k @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.Configurator.configure @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.Base.r.addMembers.initConfig @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.initComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.constructor @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1ak @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.widget @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.create @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.lookupComponent @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.privates.prepareItems @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.add @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.Ajax.request.success @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.apply.callback @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.onComplete @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1Ext.cmd.derive.onStateChange @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1(anonymous function) @ app.js?_dc=1482256653415:1
```

The `sencha app build` command completed successfully and there are no JS errors occurring locally.

Could this be something to do with production build settings when the app gets bundled? If I remove the new component the app deploy's and runs perfectly.

Comment: may be you need to build your app again. Try clearing the build folder before you rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turns out i was not including 'Ext.form.Label' in the requires array in the new component. This is really obvious now, but i'm confused why there was no error in my localhost version. Could my local version be automatically including this reference if it's not declared ?

Comment: In future you may also try `sencha app build testing` which should show you much more info.

Answer (score 1):

I was not including 'Ext.form.Label' in the requires array in the new component. This was causing the 404 which in turn was causing the second error mentioned above.